# What is difference between List.from and List.add

Tags: list, flutter

sir, I am working on flutter. I want to know the difference between both codes.

```
points = List.add(DrawingArea(
                                  point: details.localPosition,
                                  areaPaint: Paint()
                                    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                                    ..blendMode = BlendMode.clear
                                    ..color = Colors.transparent
                                    ..isAntiAlias = true
                                    ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth))

points = List.from(points)..add(DrawingArea(
                                  point: details.localPosition,
                                  areaPaint: Paint()
                                    ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
                                    ..blendMode = BlendMode.clear
                                    ..color = Colors.transparent
                                    ..isAntiAlias = true
                                    ..strokeWidth = strokeWidth))
```

Answer (score 1):

List.add adds a single entry, List.from creates a list from another list (multiples entries)